# TS2554 Expected 1 argument but got 0 for HTMLImageElement onerror()

Tags: typescript

I'm creating an image and attaching an `onload` handler that calls `onerror` when something bad happens:

```
var image = new Image();
image.onload = function() {
    let img = this as HTMLImageElement;
    if (...) {
        img.onerror();
    }
};
```

but I'm getting this error for the `img.onerror()` line:

```
TS2554 Expected 1 argument but got 0
```

How can I fix it? What is the argument expected for `onerror`?

Comment: check this out for example - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onerror_dom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in MDN's documentation for [GlobalEventHandlers.onerror](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror):

> `element.onerror` accepts a function with a single argument of type [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event)

This applies to all element types, including `HTMLImageElement`. For error handlers, it seems logical to use `ErrorEvent` objects, so you can do something like this in your code:

```js
if (...) {
    let event = new ErrorEvent('error', {
        message: 'Something bad happened.'
    });
    img.onerror(event);
}
```

Note, however, that the above code just calls the attached event handler immediately (and will fail if `img.onerror` is not set to a function).

A more elegant solution would be to just trigger the event and let the browser handle it the same way it handles all other events, including bubbling to parent elements, etc. You can achieve this very easily by replacing `img.onerror(event)` with `img.dispatchEvent(event)`.

More information about triggering events can be found in [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events#Triggering_built-in_events).